# Editing previous line in bash

Tags: bash

I was following this tutorial (below) to install OpenFoam, it was working fine up until i got to 3:54, where in the bash terminal the guy altered the code on a previous line to add -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 , when i try to do this it wont let me make any changes on the previous lines of the code.

Would anybody have an idea of why I cant do this and what I need to do to be able to add this line?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwNrVvJ2a6A&lc=UgyfbjEaLDZUS3MuTTR4AaABAg&ab_channel=ignite.byu.edu

Comment: You have to open the file in a text editor. If you don't know any terminal based editors (the tutorial uses Vim but it's not an easy thing to get started with), you can instead open the file with a graphical text editor and make the change there.

Comment: What does "it wont let me make any changes" mean? What editor are you using? Is there an error message? What is the message?